# import FileHandle across Node.js versions

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Is there a way to import FileHandle across stable Node.js versions?**

I mean in Node.js v14 an v16 following code works fine

```
import { FileHandle } from "fs/promises";
```

but in Node.js v12 it doesn't work, so I tried with

```
import { promises } from "fs";
const { FileHandle } = promises;
```

but this doesn't work on Node.js v16.

According with [Node.js Release](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#readme) v12 is still supported.

So: **how can I import FileHandle in a package and make the package compliant with all supported Node.js versions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 imports are an [experimental feature](https://nodejs.org/dist./v12.12.0/docs/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) within Node v12. If you want to make your application compatible with Node v12, you could use `require`

```
const fileHandle = require("fs").promises;
```

which works in Node versions v12, v14, and v16